# Simple logic operation >> &

Tags: bit-manipulation

I can't find out what lane below means:

```
pclkdiv = (LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 >> 18) & 0x03;
```

What does operation >> and & stands for?
PCLKSEL1 is 32bit register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code isolates the two bits indicated by the arrows below, and moves them to the two least significant bit positions.

```
            vv
11111111111111111111111111111111 original value
                              vv
00000000000000000011111111111111 after >>18 (shift right 18 positions)
                              vv
00000000000000000000000000000011 after & 3 (mask out all but the 0th and 1st bits)
```

This assumes an unsigned value, and no special handling of the sign bit during the shift. The & (AND) is a masking operation because for the result to be 1 at any position, both the value and the mask must be 1 (i.e. 1 AND 1 = 1, all else is 0. So only the bits in the mask (the 0x03 in your case) can end up with anything other than 0, and they will only be 1 if they were 1 in the value being masked.

Answer (score 0):

> > is bit shift right operation.

If PCLKSEL1 has binary value 'ABCDEFGHIJK101abcdefghijklmnpqrs' where (A-P and a-s are 0 or 1 respectively), PCLKSEL1>> 18 will become "000000000000000000ABCDEFGHIJK101".

& is bitwise AND operator. The n-th bit of the result of ( X & Y ) is AND of n-th bit of X and n-th bit of Y.

If PCLKSEL1 has binary value 'ABCDEFGHIJK101abcdefghijklmnpqrs', (PCLKSEL1 >> 18) & 0x03 will become '00000000000000000000000000000101'

In the othre words, (PCLKSEL1 >> 18) & 0x03 is operation to extract 12-th to 14-th bits from leftmost.